# What WPF control should I used to build a high performance grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

What WPF control should I used to build a high performance grid?

I want to be able to have cell level control so I can update a cell and have the grid only redraw that cell.

The DataGrid doesn't seem to give cell level control.

I need to support 10000 rows with lots of cell updates (say 200 per second).

Thanks

Comment: Is it 200 per second and cell, or 200 per second overall?

Comment: 200 per second overall - thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IF you need performance, your best option is to *measure, measure, measure*.

Build a quick prototype using each of the DataGrid classes you're looking at, using "realistic" sample data.

See which ones perform well, and which ones don't.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to try 3rd party data grids then did u atleast give WPF Datagrid a try? It does support virtualization at row and column level. Plus cell level control is available thru CellStyle for DataGridCell type. You can even attach any behavior to DataGridCell and then gain exclusive access over it and drill into its visual tree and perform any kind of performance improvements you want locally to its contents.

I have been using WPF datagrid for various requirements (hierarchical data display without row definitions and group styles, frequent data updates, large number of columns, frequent editable and validation based scenarios, adorning virtulaized cells and deferred scrolling with guesswork for scroll heuristics etc..)

You can play around with it to the fullest. Codeplex website has source code of last toolkit based WPF data grid available.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The Telerik RadGrid for WPF supports both Row- and Column-Virtualization and might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Doesn't the built-in WPF DataGrid support Virtualization too?

Comment: Yes it does. We do have a similar scenario and it is working pretty good.

Comment: I think the built-in grid only supports Row Virtualization.

Comment: That's right I guess. But that should be good enough, right? Depending on the numer of rows of course.

Comment: WPF DataGrid has a `EnableRowVirtualization` and a `EnableColumnVirtualization` property, so it supports both. Just the default is different: RowVirtualization is on by default, ColumnVirtualization is off.

Answer (score -1):

I'd not refuse a-priori a winform-approach since the huge amount of data and the relatively high speed of the updates. In a similar scenario, you may manage even much more data without affecting the performance significantly.

I'm a big fan of WPF, but not always it solve all the problems.